# MySQL query by age range on a table which have date of birth

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have MySQL table with a date of birth. And I want to query the rows which based on age for current date. So following is the query for the table with date range.

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `dob` > '1980-01-20' AND `dob` < '1990-01-20';
```

How can we convert this query to search with age range for the current date in the same table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `year` function to extract the year part of the current date. So, for example, if you're looking for users between the ages of 24 and 34:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `user` 
WHERE  (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(`dob`)) BETWEEN 24 AND 34
```

Comment: It is working fine thank you. Is it possible to include month also?

Comment: @anonymous Anything's possible - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: simply if I want to get above 20 year the dob need to be before (1994-07-29). Will the above code do such a filter? or is it looking for dob of 1994 and before?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT U.*
    ,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),U.dob)), ‘%Y’)+0 AS age
FROM `user` U
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),U.dob)), ‘%Y’)+0 BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

In this example, you'll have every users with age in the range `20-30`.

Hope this will help you

Comment: I don't know if it was important but this query take the entire date into consideration to define the real age (13. december 2000 => 12 years old and not 13 yet)

Comment: your answer is working thats why i put up vote. But I wanted minimum lines of query because i'm wringing a large number of join. So I choose to go with the minimum effort answer. Any way thanks to the working answer.

Comment: @anonymous The most important is that you've a solution for your problem.

Comment: you are correct all 3 answers are working for my requirement. And i'm not looking into month and date level accuracy. So better to choose the query with few lines. Any how your answer is more accurate. And i can only select one green answer. thats why i put up vote to other answers.

Comment: This is best accurate answer I guess. as I tested for birthdate 1999-05-03 and today date id 2019-04-18. so, the age is 19 years 11 months 15 days. @JoëlSalamin answer give more accurate (19 Yr) and "Mureinik" is answer is working but it gives age 20.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to get all users with age between 15 and 20 years

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE birthday <= now() - INTERVAL 15 YEAR and
      birthday > now() - INTERVAL 21 YEAR
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) >= 25
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) <= 30
```